# Wordpress get_query_var with PHPUnit empty

Tags: wordpress, phpunit

I want to test a custom query_var that I have created. When I run the website the query_var is correct. However when I test with PHPUnit, it seems that PHPUnit does not see the query_var?

What I do is the following:

```
public function test_correct_category_name() {

    $this->go_to('/category/cars');
    $category_name = get_query_var( 'category' );

    $this->assertEquals( $category_name, 'cars');
}
```

Again, this works perfect when opening the website and output `echo get_query_var( 'category' );` then it shows `cars`;

How do you do this?

Comment: I think I have a bad news for you. Despite being very popular Wordpress code is quite mess and it's very difficult to write unit test for it because a lot of external dependencies, simply it's very difficult to isolate tested code.
I would suggest something like behat and test directly website and it's features.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have taken a look at Behat. Looks promising, however for this particular case I really want it to work. Do you have experience with this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where the clue lies. Take a look at this StackOverflow post: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71406/is-there-a-flowchart-for-wordpress-loading-sequence Especial the flowchart with the actions sequence on it.

I found that in the test I have to set the query_var with `set_query_var( 'category', 'cars' );`
So I can test it.

In my Category class I init it on `template_redirect` so that $wp_query is instantiated. In $wp_query the query_vars are accessible. Now the class does not give an error when it calls: `get_query_var`.

Whew, that took me days to figure out..